# cannot implicitly convert type in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, dto

I was about to build a DTO for list of the data.

```
return from p in db.Students.Find(Id).Courses
       select new CourseDTO
       {
           Id = p.Id,
           CourseName = p.CourseName
       };
```

However, when I use this, I get the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Storage.Models.CourseDTO>' to 
'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Storage.Models.CourseDTO>'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Show the function signature..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You method's return type is `ICollection<T>` but the query returns an `IEnumerable<T>` (or  an `IQueryable<T>`). Most likely you don't need an `ICollection<T>` anyway, and if you did, what would you expect that collection to do? It couldn't be used to manipulate the database. If all you're doing is querying the database, then change the return type of your method to `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public IEnumerable<CourseDTO> MyMethod(int Id) 
{
    return from p in db.Students.Find(Id).Courses
           select new CourseDTO
           {
               Id = p.Id,
               CourseName = p.CourseName

           };
}
```

Comment: If you don't have to return a `List` this solution is preferred since it consumes less memory.

Comment: +1 for not supplying the easiest solution and going with `.ToList()` with your eyes closed..

Answer (score 7):

```
return (from p in db.Students.Find(Id).Courses
           select new CourseDTO
           {
               Id = p.Id,
               CourseName = p.CourseName

           }).ToList();
```

Comment: This is less preferred... I would go with changing the function signature to `IEnumerable` unless I have to get a `List`

Comment: This actually is preferred when you want to be sure that the results are materialized, although the OP doesn't state that.